# gmdate() returning 2 different results in 2 different controllers (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a situation where I am using the php function gmdate() in two different codeigniter controllers.  The controllers are returning a 6 hour difference with the exact same calls.

Below is the controller that is returning the proper GMT date and below that is the one that is 6 hours off.  Hopefully this is just an oversight on my part somewhere.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    public function update_current_user($session_id){
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $currentURL = base_url().uri_string();

    $updateData = array(
            'id'=>$session_id   ,
            'last_updated'=>gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()),   
            'current_url'=> $currentURL
        );
    $this->db->where('id',$session_id);
    $this->db->update('current_visitors', $updateData);
    return true;
}
```

Below is the one where it is returning 6 hours off.

```
    public function initiate_chat($id,$name)
{
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $currentURL = base_url().uri_string();

    $updateData = array(
            'id'=>$id   ,
            'last_updated'=>gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()),
            'chat_requested_time'=>gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()),    
            'requested_chat'=>1,    
            'name'=>$name,
        );
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('current_visitors', $updateData);
    return $name;           
}
```

Comment: do you have any date_default_timezone_set in the controllers, that might be throwing it off? If not you could try put one in each of the controllers setting it to the correct timezone, to see if it makes any difference

Comment: I did not have date_default_timezone_set in any of them.  However I just put that in both of them and now they are showing consistent results.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Set, default timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
to one value then, you will get same value. Or use it where you are going to use date/time functions.
For eg:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$curTime = gmdate('H:i:s',time());
```

It will return the current time with timezone set to GMT.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem related with Codeigniter and PHP 5.

You should set a default timezone in your php.ini file or you can use the solution provided by Phil Sturgeon, otherwise you will run into this problem everytime you'll make use of date/time functions

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/12/CodeIgniter-on-PHP-5.3